# Adobe Photoshop CS5 [mac] - drag and drop to open

Tags: mac, adobe-photoshop

Adobe Photoshop CS5 has new feature - when file is dropped from finder onto document, it creates new smart layer with contents.

What do I have to do to open the file instead creating new layer?

Thank you.

P.S.: It drives me crazy.

Comment: No kidding. I've got this exact same issue. Did Adobe actually test this before they released it? It's maddening! (Also: Have you tried dragging a layer over to another file you have open using the tabs at the top? It won't let you! Unbelievable!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out! Just drag the files to the grey bar at the top (where the tools are) instead of the paste board. Photoshop 5 will open the file and not just create a new layer in the currently opened document.

Hurrah.

Comment: I absolutely forgot about this question! It's also (as I figured out back then) to drag&drop the file onto the icon.